# biblatex 3.0 and APA citation styles

Tags: biblatex, luatex, biber, apa-style, apa6

I am using biblatex 3.0 (current with the TeX Live 2015 pretest) and hope to hove APA citations and a bibliography. Instead, the relevant lines shown below in LuaLaTeX generate a PDF with no bibliography printed and boldfaced BibTeX labels standing in for any citation. What am I doing wrong here?

```
% !BIB TS-program = biber
% !BIB program = biber
\documentclass[11pt,english]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{myfile.bib}
\begin{document}
\textcite{label}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome, the standard question seems to apply here, regardless of the version: Have you run `biber`? If yes, what does the `blg` file say?

Comment: btw, package `inputenc` will be of no use here, it could be of harm in the worst case.

Comment: Is `bibtexcode` a citing target contained in `myfile.bib`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer The edit now says BibTeX label, if that helps. Yet, the labels actually appear in the file.

Comment: @Johannes_B I am new to biblatex. Doesn't biber run if you run LuaLaTeX on the tex file itself? How do you run biber separately, then? (Which can easily be the mistake.)

Comment: [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154767)

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks, but now adding the two lines I know show in the edit does not help LuaLaTeX compiling a bibliography and citations. Shall I do more than in TeXShop Typeset with LuaLaTeX?

Comment: I see. Having a "BibTeX" run actually calls Biber. By the way, I learnt I still have only 2.0.

Comment: `biblatex 3.0` and `biber 2.0` are happily in love. That's correct. `biblatex 2.0` would be really old.

Comment: This is most likely a duplicate of [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852)

Comment: I ran into an unrelated error, so I quickly opened a separate question for it. Thanks for the help. http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/241433/26387