# biblatex 3.0 apa undefined control sequence (\mkbibdateapalongextra?)

Tags: biblatex, luatex, biber, apa-style, apa6

I am not sure why I cannot copy from the TeXShop console anymore, but here is my problem. This does not seem to be related to my bib file or how I cite things. How can I fix this?

I am calling LuaLaTeX here on after calling biber 2.0.

[image]

The example code would look like the following. From the error message, it does not look like any other specifics (of the content, for instance) is related to the error.

```
% !BIB TS-program = biber
% !BIB program = biber
\documentclass[11pt,english]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{myfile.bib}
\begin{document}
\textcite{label}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you sure that all your question that will come up now are related to the new release of `biblatex`? Can you please try with version `2.9a` (or whatever the latest wa) in an extra folder?

Comment: To reproduce your error and hellp we need to see some code, please provide a minimal working example as seen in you other post.

Comment: @Johannes_B I am happy to revert to earlier versions. Are you aware of a go-to guide to how do this in an extra folder?

Comment: [Polyglossia and biblatex-apa](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48557)

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks again. Note that using `\usepackage[english]{babel}` (or nothing) does not help, even though a comment from 2012 on the linked question says `Biblatex-apa now includes an english.lbx. Also, remember that biblatex doesn't really support polyglossia, only babel`

Comment: Have you included the line that is needed as it defines the macro you are missing? `\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}` The problem with other question was the missing language mapping. That is fixed by now. ut, you need to load *one* language mapping, which isn't the case above.

Comment: So using `english` is not supposed to work? Even there is an `english.lbx` (which I could not verify, I cannot find the right folder in my installation)? Note I did not use `british` here.

Comment: So use `\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}`